Ассоциация, ведущая на удалённый вопрос
На вопросе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285211/overriding-interface-property-type-defined-in-typescript-d-ts-file показывается плашка «На этот вопрос есть ответы на Stack Overflow на русском»

Однако при переходе по ней
«Этот вопрос был удалён с сайта Stack Overflow на русском в процессе модерации»

Нужно удалить неправильную ассоциацию из настроек сайта.

MSE и наша Мета

@αλεχολυτ и оба без ответов :-D

Свидетельство того, что сотрудники не заинтересованы

@αλεχολυτ, ПОЭТОМУ ИХ И НАДА ЗАИНТЕРЕСОВАТЬ

@αλεχολυτ, КСТАТИ НА НАШЕЙ МЕТЕ СИТУАЦИЯ НЕМНОГО ДРУГАЯ - И РЕШИЛАСЬ ВОССТАНОВЛЕНИЕМ НАШЕГО ВОПРОСА С ОТВЕТОМ, А В ТЕКУЩЕМ СЛУЧАЕ САМА ФУНКЦИОНАЛЬНОСТЬ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНА НЕПРАВИЛЬНО И КОММЕНТАРИЙ С АССОЦИАЦИЕЙ БЫЛ ДОБАВЛЕН В ВОПРОС БЕЗ ОТВЕТА.

@αλεχολυτ, Grundy, первый раз вижу, чтобы вопрос enSO закрывали вопросом ruSO. Есть ли обратная практика для закрытия ruSO вопросом enSO? А то вижу, как другие просто оставляют в комментариях под вопросом ruSO ссылку на вопрос enSO.

@Chaos_Sower, ЕГО НЕ ЗАКРЫВАЮТ ВОПРОСОМ RUSO - ИХ ПРОСТО СВЯЗЫВАЮТ. МОЖЕШЬ ПОСМОТРЕТЬ ВОПРОСЫ Ассоциация вопросов между сайтами доступна! Инструменты ассоциации вопросов между сайтами Повысим интерес коллег к работе с помощью знаний! И ДРУГИЕ СВЯЗАННЫЕ ВОПРОСЫ
